# How can I turn the below code into one <div>?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

Right now If I have them together when `showLanguageControl` is true, it looks fine. However when `showFaxNumber` is true, the placement is way off, even if `showLanguageControl` is hidden. Is it possible to put combine these two?

Either that, or I need both `<div>` in the same position dependent on which one is true. For more info, neither will be true at the same time.

```
<!--open text box if language control is true-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" [style.visibility]="showLanguageControl === true ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-5" for="providerRoute">Linked Language Letter</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-7 padding-adj">
            <input type="text" id="linkedLetter" name="linkedLetter" #linkedLetter formControlName="linkedLetter" [ngClass]="['form-control','input-xs']" />
        </div>
    </div>

          <!--open text box if exception group is true-->
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" [style.visibility]="showFaxNumberInput === true ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-5" for="providerRoute">Fax Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-7 padding-adj">
           <input type="text" id="faxInput" name="faxInput" #faxInput formControlName="faxInput" [ngClass]="['form-control','input-xs']" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: We can't really help you right now because layout issues are generally rooted in CSS, but there's 1,001+ reasons for any CSS layout issues so *we need to see a working example*, not a small HTML fragment without any context. Also, your posted HTML is not actually HTML, it's an Angular template - what we need to see is your actual in-browser DOM (no, not a screenshot) and how the style-rules are being applied.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I'll work on getting you that info

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I changed the following line from:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" [style.visibility]="showLanguageControl === true ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
```

To:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" [style.display]="showLanguageControl === true ? 'block' : 'none'">
```

Doing it this way takes that entire piece of UI out of the DOM, allowing a different piece of UI to be on top of where it *would be* if it was still there.